# Using a non-isolated DC power source for a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, isolation

I am designing a frequency converter for an approximately 200W three-phase motor operating at 220VAC. I intend to use a microcontroller for control and measurements. To cut costs, I am considering using a non-isolated AC/DC converter to supply power to the microcontroller and measurement circuits. Is this approach electronically safe? By safety, I am not referring to human safety, as that is not a primary concern. I am concerned about potential issues with the microcontroller, such as obtaining inaccurate measurements or damaging the microcontroller. Your insights are appreciated.

Comment: This is done often. You just need to implement it properly. It's a pretty big PITA to isolate the MCU supply as well as all signals from the power side to the MCU so often you don't, and just have an isolated interface with a second isolated MCU since that can just be a few isolated serial lines.

Comment: Hi @DKNguyen , What you mentioned is exactly what I want to do, but I'm unsure how long it can operate correctly or if something might get damaged.

Comment: I think you're overthinking it. You have a DC link so you don't need to worry about negative AC getting into your logic. Just rate your components properly.

Comment: What external/remote circuits/interfaces are controlling the micro?